# Kotlin coroutines - how to run in background and use result in the caller thread?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The main idea is to have non-suspend function `runInBackgroundAndUseInCallerThread(callback: (SomeModel) -> Unit)` which run some work asynchronously in background (another thread) and after work is done - run callback in the caller thread (thread that launched `runInBackgroundAndUseInCallerThread`).

Below I wrote an example code, but I'm not sure how correct it is and whether it is possible at all. With the `println("1/2/3/...")` I marked the desired call order. 
`getDispatcherFromCurrentThread` - if is possible to implement this function, then solution can be used, but I don't know how to implement it and is it right to do it like that at all.

Therefore, please do not consider it as the only solution.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

fun main() {
    println("1")
    runInBackgroundAndUseInCallerThread {
        println("4")
        println("Hello ${it.someField} from ${Thread.currentThread().name}") // should be "Hello TestField from main"
    }
    println("2")
    thread(name = "Second thread") {
        runInBackgroundAndUseInCallerThread {
            println("5")
            println("Hello ${it.someField} from ${Thread.currentThread().name}") // should be "Hello TestField from Second thread"
        }
    }
    println("3")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    println("6")
}

fun runInBackgroundAndUseInCallerThread(callback: (SomeModel) -> Unit) {
    val dispatcherFromCallerThread: CoroutineDispatcher = getDispatcherFromCurrentThread()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val result: SomeModel = getModelResult()
        launch(dispatcherFromCallerThread) { callback(result) }
    }
}

data class SomeModel(val someField: String)

suspend fun getModelResult(): SomeModel {
    delay(1000)
    return SomeModel("TestField")
}

fun getDispatcherFromCurrentThread(): CoroutineDispatcher {
    // TODO: Create dispatcher from current thread... How to do that?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the thread is designed to work as a dispatcher there isn't a universal way to make it do so.
The only way which comes to mind is the fact that `runBlocking` is re-entrant and will create an event-loop in the existing thread, however it will block all non-coroutine code from executing on that thread until it completes.

This ends up looking like:

```
fun runInBackgroundAndUseInCallerThread(callback: (SomeModel) -> Unit) {
    callback(runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
        getModelResult()
    })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will block the caller thread (as you said) and that's contadics with the main idea about asynchronous call.

Comment: In the end something will need to block the thread while waiting for work and without establishing a contract the only reliable way to do this is to do the blocking and handling of dispatched code yourself (by calling `runBlocking`)

Answer (score 1):

`dispatcher` really is a `coroutineContext` and it is meaningful when used inside a `scope` 
thus if you want pass dispatcher of parent scope to child scope you can do it.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
        val dispatcher = this.coroutineContext
        CoroutineScope(dispatcher).launch {

        }
}
```

therefor  `getDispatcherFromCurrentThread` should be like this.

```
fun getDispatcherFromCurrentThread(scope: CoroutineScope): CoroutineContext {
    return scope.coroutineContext
}
```

and

```
GlobalScope.launch {
            val dispatcher = getDispatcherFromCurrentThread(this)
            CoroutineScope(dispatcher).launch {

            }
    }
```

Comment: This is not what is described in the topic.

Answer (score 0):

> which run some work asynchronously in background (another thread) and after work is done - run callback in the caller thread

First try to answer this question: *what is the calling thread supposed to do while the background work is in progress*?

Clearly it can't go on to the next line of your code, which is supposed to run after finishing the background work.

You also don't want it to block and wait.

What code should it run, then?

And the only reasonable answer is as follows: the calling thread should, at its topmost level of execution (entry-point function), run an infinite event loop. The code in your question should be inside an event handler submitted to the event loop. At the point you want to wait for the background work, the handler must return so the thread can go on handling other events, and you must have another handler ready to submit when the background work is done. This second handler, corresponding to your `callback`, is called the *continuation* and Kotlin provides it automatically. You don't in fact need your own callback.

However, now the most sensitive issue arises: how will you submit the continuation to the event loop? This is not something you can abstract over, you must use some API *specific to the event loop in question*.

And this is why Kotlin has the notion of a `Dispatcher`. It captures the case-specific concern of dispatching continuations to the desired thread. You seem to want to solve it without the need to write a dispatcher dedicated to each specific event loop, and unfortunately this is impossible.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. 
Let's assume that I run `fun runInBackgroundAndUseInCallerThread` in the GUI thread and I want to do the work in the background and then run the callback in the GUI, but I don't want to hardcode the `Dispatchers.Main`.
This 'fun' I also want to be able to run inside some Service that works in the background (non GUI), not block it, and run callback in the thread of this Service.

Comment: `run callback in the thread of this Service` -- here we come back to the issue in my answer. You need a way of submitting an event to the service thread. You can't solve this problem generally because the `Thread` abstraction doesn't have any inherent event loop associated with it. So unless you're able to `launch(serviceThreadDispatcher)` and then do everything the usual way, you can't achieve your goal.